# PHP: Parallel cURL Performance - RollingCurl vs ParallelCurl

Tags: php, curl, parallel-processing, curl-multi

I have a large amount of cURL requests to process. There are a couple libraries I've found to help process them parallel, the main ones are RollingCurl ( http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/ ) and Parallel Curl ( https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl ).

Does anyone have experience with these libraries, and if so do you know which one performs better?

Thanks!

UPDATE: For anyone who may stumble upon this later, if you're using Rolling Curl's group functionality it seems to break when handling a large number of requests (50k+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance is not the issue since  they are both wrapping standard `but` functionality

- RollingCurl  support group process which you can also achieve with simple array
- Parallel Curl i slight ans straight froward .. with optional custom `curl` options
- They Both Support callback

Both are nice it depends on your need .....

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. I've implemented the project using Rolling Curl for now; it's doing everything I needed it too. As long as there shouldn't be any performance differences I won't bother with Parallel Curl.